# Wifi adapter will not accept any password (Error 7)

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, nmcli

I had to roll back my Kubuntu 19.10 from kernel 5.3.0-24-generic to 5.3.0-23-generic via

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.3.0-24-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-5.3.0-24-generic
```

because PC was locked at the login screen, no mouse moving or keyboard inputs and CPU @ 100% (according to fan speed).
After that, I was able to login again. But the wifi connection asks for the password. When entering it, it keeps asking. This is a bit weird because when I used the kernel 5.4.0-23 (which is active now), I never had this problem.
When connecting via terminal:

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect <SSID> password <password>
```

i get the following error:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.
```

which is the same error I get when I don't provide any password. I am 100% sure the password is correct. I also changed the password in the router, so it does not containt any special characters, same behaviour. Following some posts on arch linux forums, this can possilbly happen if two network managers are active. I am not sure if this is the case. Output of `systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled`:

```
UNIT FILE                                  STATE  
snap-core-8039.mount                       enabled
snap-core-8213.mount                       enabled
snap-core18-1265.mount                     enabled
snap-core18-1279.mount                     enabled
snap-freecad-4.mount                       enabled
snap-freecad-6.mount                       enabled
snap-freecad-8.mount                       enabled
snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-167.mount        enabled
snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-169.mount        enabled
acpid.path                                 enabled
apport-autoreport.path                     enabled
cups.path                                  enabled
accounts-daemon.service                    enabled
anacron.service                            enabled
apparmor.service                           enabled
atd.service                                enabled
autofs.service                             enabled
autovt@.service                            enabled
avahi-daemon.service                       enabled
binfmt-support.service                     enabled
blk-availability.service                   enabled
bluetooth.service                          enabled
console-setup.service                      enabled
cron.service                               enabled
cups-browsed.service                       enabled
cups.service                               enabled
dbus-fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service         enabled
dbus-org.bluez.service                     enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service         enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service      enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.thermald.service      enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.timesync1.service     enabled
dmesg.service                              enabled
e2scrub_reap.service                       enabled
getty@.service                             enabled
gpu-manager.service                        enabled
grub-initrd-fallback.service               enabled
haveged.service                            enabled
irexec.service                             enabled
irqbalance.service                         enabled
kerneloops.service                         enabled
keyboard-setup.service                     enabled
lircd-setup.service                        enabled
lircd-uinput.service                       enabled
lircd.service                              enabled
lircmd.service                             enabled
lm-sensors.service                         enabled
lvm2-monitor.service                       enabled
ModemManager.service                       enabled
mpd.service                                enabled
network-manager.service                    enabled
networkd-dispatcher.service                enabled
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service          enabled
NetworkManager-wait-online.service         enabled
NetworkManager.service                     enabled
nfs-kernel-server.service                  enabled
nfs-server.service                         enabled
nmbd.service                               enabled
ondemand.service                           enabled
portmap.service                            enabled
pppd-dns.service                           enabled
rpcbind.service                            enabled
rsync.service                              enabled
rsyslog.service                            enabled
secureboot-db.service                      enabled
setvtrgb.service                           enabled
smbd.service                               enabled
snapd.autoimport.service                   enabled
snapd.core-fixup.service                   enabled
snapd.seeded.service                       enabled
snapd.service                              enabled
snapd.system-shutdown.service              enabled
spice-vdagent.service                      enabled
spice-vdagentd.service                     enabled
syslog.service                             enabled
systemd-resolved.service                   enabled
systemd-timesyncd.service                  enabled
teamviewerd.service                        enabled
thermald.service                           enabled
tlp-sleep.service                          enabled
tlp.service                                enabled
udisks2.service                            enabled
ufw.service                                enabled
unattended-upgrades.service                enabled
vboxautostart-service.service              enabled
vboxballoonctrl-service.service            enabled
vboxdrv.service                            enabled
vboxweb-service.service                    enabled
whoopsie.service                           enabled
wpa_supplicant.service                     enabled
acpid.socket                               enabled
apport-forward.socket                      enabled
avahi-daemon.socket                        enabled
cups.socket                                enabled
dm-event.socket                            enabled
lircd.socket                               enabled
lvm2-lvmpolld.socket                       enabled
mpd.socket                                 enabled
rpcbind.socket                             enabled
snapd.socket                               enabled
spice-vdagentd.socket                      enabled
uuidd.socket                               enabled
nfs-client.target                          enabled
remote-fs.target                           enabled
anacron.timer                              enabled
apt-daily-upgrade.timer                    enabled
apt-daily.timer                            enabled
e2scrub_all.timer                          enabled
fstrim.timer                               enabled
logrotate.timer                            enabled
man-db.timer                               enabled
motd-news.timer                            enabled
snapd.snap-repair.timer                    enabled
```

output of `service --status-all`:

```
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ + ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  atd
 [ + ]  autofs
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  binfmt-support
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cryptdisks
 [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  ecbd
 [ - ]  gdomap
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  haveged
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ - ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lircd
 [ + ]  lircmd
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  mpd
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ - ]  nfs-common
 [ + ]  nfs-kernel-server
 [ + ]  nmbd
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  procps
 [ + ]  rpcbind
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  samba-ad-dc
 [ - ]  saned
 [ + ]  sddm
 [ + ]  smbd
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  tlp
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ + ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```